# How would I compare the values in each set of 4 rows to one value (Wilcox test specifying mu)?

Tags: r, statistics, mapply, pairwise.wilcox.test

I need to compare the value in every four rows to one value (as mu) using a Wilcoxon signed rank sum test. For example if my data looks like this:

```
df1 <- c(0.205346764819837, 0.260927758796802, 0.243880102849495, 0.244549329012715, 
      0.122609277587968, 0.19381141911169, 0.0617801415941672, 0.217762671269064, 
      0.0513190799901377, 0.293455672572294, 0.222447254411609, 0.271001373674756, 
      0.00119756260786869, 0.119069423408827, -0.0164312634285513, 
      0.0446268183579303)

     
df2 <- c(0.23340509, 0.05959987, 0.17380963, 0.14517836)
```

I am using a `wilcox.test` to compare each of the four values from df1 with one value as mu from df_stack2.  Considering a df with just the first four rows it would be

```
wilcox.test(dfnew$A, mu=0.23340509)$p.value.
```

I realise I could group every four rows through using:

```
split(df, as.integer(gl(nrow(df) 4, nrow(df))))
```

I was hoping to adopt this for use in a mapply (so I could parallelise with future.apply due to the actual size of my dataframe), however, I am a little unsure as to how I could specify every four rows being compared to one value (in a separate dataframe) as mu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your group using `rep()` and apply your function by group:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfnew)[, grp:=rep(1:(.N/4), each=4, length.out=.N)]
dfnew[, .(pval = wilcox.test(A, mu=df2[.BY$grp])$p.value), grp]
```

Output:

```
     grp  pval
   <int> <num>
1:     1 0.875
2:     2 0.125
3:     3 0.875
4:     4 0.125
```

Similarly, using `dplyr`:

```
dfnew %>% 
  group_by(grp = rep(1:(n()/4), each=4, length.out=n())) %>% 
  summarize(pval = wilcox.test(A,mu = df2[cur_group()$grp])$p.value)
```

Output:

```
    grp  pval
  <int> <dbl>
1     1 0.875
2     2 0.125
3     3 0.875
4     4 0.125
```

There is another approach that you might find interesting:

```
setDT(dfnew)[, .(pval = wilcox.test(A, mu=.BY$mu)$p.value), .(mu = rep(df2, each=4))]
```

Output:

```
           mu  pval
        <num> <num>
1: 0.23340509 0.875
2: 0.05959987 0.125
3: 0.17380963 0.875
4: 0.14517836 0.125
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of 4 elements where each element of the list contains every four values of `df1`. Then using `map2()` from `purrr` package or `tidyverse()` family you could provide  for each chunck of splitted list the corresponding `mu` from `df2`:

```
library(tidyverse)

# split df1 into 4 chunks of size 4 (or 4 elements of size 4)

      df1split <- split(df1, ceiling(seq_along(df1) / 4))

#calculate wilcoxon test for each chunk using map2()

      map2(df1split,df2, ~ wilcox.test(.x, mu =.y)$p.value) 

$`1`
[1] 0.875       # pvalue of first chunk 

$`2`
[1] 0.125       # pvalue of second chunk

$`3`
[1] 0.875       # pvalue of third chunk

$`4`
[1] 0.125       # pvalue of fourth chunk
```

To return `p-values` from list into a data frame you can add the following codes to `map2()`:

```
map2(df1split,df2, ~ wilcox.test(.x, mu =.y)$p.value) %>% 
     bind_rows() %>% t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
     rename("p-value" = "V1")

    
  p-value
1  0.875
2  0.125
3  0.875
4  0.125
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with another library:

```
library(matrixTests)

# turn each 4-observation entry into a separate row in a matrix:
m1 <- matrix(df1, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)

# perform the test:
row_wilcoxon_onesample(m1, df2)
  obs statistic pvalue location.null alternative exact corrected
1   4         6  0.875    0.23340509   two.sided  TRUE     FALSE
2   4        10  0.125    0.05959987   two.sided  TRUE     FALSE
3   4         6  0.875    0.17380963   two.sided  TRUE     FALSE
4   4         0  0.125    0.14517836   two.sided  TRUE     FALSE
```